# JPA Nested Mapping to View without a Base Table

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

So I have this view called OmsJob. I'm mappint it to a POJO and it has `draftFile`, `trackedFile`, `cleanFile`, and other files linked with the *files* table. And as usual, I mapped those like this:

```java
@Entity
@EntityListeners(PreventAnyUpdate.class)
@ConfigurationProperties("omsjob")
@Table(name = "OMSJob")
public class OmsJob {
    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "draft_file_id")
    private SomeFile draftFile;
}
```

which works fine and is basically:

```json
{
  "omsjob": {
    "draftFile": {}
  }
}
```

But I want it like:

```json
{
  "omsjob": {
    "fileDetails": {
      "draftFile": {}
    }
  }
}
```

So I created a class and named it FileDetails and made it `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded` it into OmsJob like this:

```java
@Embeddable
public class FileDetails {
    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "draftFileId")
    private SomeFile draftFile;
}

@Entity
@EntityListeners(PreventAnyUpdate.class)
@ConfigurationProperties("omsjob")
@Table(name = "OMSJob")
public class OmsJob {
    @Embedded
    private FileDetails fileDetails;
}
```

The error I got is obvious, `Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 'MySchema.OMSJob' is not BASE TABLE`. It was trying to add foreign keys to the table and I've mapped it to the view. But how can I achieve what I'm trying to and is this even the right way?

### Update 1

The code is working, it just throws the error while starting the application. Should find a way to handle that error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just need to add `@javax.persistence.ForeignKey` annotation to prevent JPA from adding a foreign key:

```java
@Embeddable
public class FileDetails {

    @NotNull
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "draftFileId", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none"))
    private SomeFile draftFile;

    /**
     * @return the draftFile
     */
    public SomeFile getDraftFile() {
        return draftFile;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error with the `@` in front of ForeignKey; works without the `@`